# How do I make this loop work?

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

I'm supposed to be gathering input of numbers until the user types '0'. 
Also once the user decides to exit the loop, the user can decide whether to start again or not. 
How do I fix my program? Or is there another way that is more efficient to deliver this program?

`

```
int regular, special, vip;
int i;
bool flag = true;

while(flag)
{
    cout << "input please: ";
    cin >> i;

    if ((i <10000) && (i > 0))
    {
        regular++;
    }

    if ((i >10000) && (i<=50000))
    {
        special++;
    }

    if (i > 50000)
    {
        vip++;
    }

    if (i==0);
    {
        flag = false;
        cout << "Your branch has " << regular <<  " Regular Customers, "
            <<  special << " Special Customers and " << vip << " VIP Customers"
        << "Try again? [1 = yes/ 0 = no] " << endl;
    }
}
```

}`

Comment: A good place to start would be to remove the semi-colon from `if (i==0);`

Comment: @paddy OnAncientJoke: `if(incoming_detected()); launch_nuclear_counterstrike();`

Comment: jfc im blind thanks!

Comment: Side note: what do you want to do when `i == 10000`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. `cout` before setting `flag` to false.

Also remove semicolon after `if(i==0)`

```
int regular, special, vip;
int i;
bool flag = true;

while(flag)
{
    cout << "input please: ";
    cin >> i;

    if ((i <10000) && (i > 0))
    {
        regular++;
    }

    if ((i >10000) && (i<=50000))
    {
        special++;
    }

    if (i > 50000)
    {
        vip++;
    }

    if (i==0)
    {
        cout << "Your branch has " << regular <<  " Regular Customers, "
             <<  special << " Special Customers and " << vip << " VIP Customers"
             << "Try again? [1 = yes/ 0 = no] " << endl;
        flag = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you just have to read in the user's choice to try again and do something based on that. Oh, and also remove the semicolon after `if(i==0)`:

```
if (i==0)
{
    flag = false;
    cout << "Your branch has " << regular <<  " Regular Customers, "
        <<  special << " Special Customers and " << vip << " VIP Customers"
    << "Try again? [1 = yes/ 0 = no] " << endl;

    /* Do what the user wants */
    cin>> i;
    if( i == 1 )
    {
        /* Reset regular, special, and vip variables if desired */

        flag = true;
    }
}
```